# how to disable autosave for tramp buffers in emacs?

Tags: emacs, tramp

autosave for tramp buffers is very annoying, every time it cost dozens of seconds.

I can disable it by using Alt-X auto-save-mode, Is there any way I can do to automatic disable it? maybe by using some kind of hook?

Comment: Which tramp method are you using?

Comment: Very annoying.  In this era of multi-core-processors and multi-threaded applications, I'm surprised it can't do its autosaving in the background so I don't have to stop working every five seconds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set `tramp-auto-save-directory` to a local directory.

```
(setq tramp-auto-save-directory "~/emacs/tramp-autosave")
```

Update: In your case, you may set `tramp-auto-save-directory` to `/tmp`.

Comment: More info is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Auto_002dsave-and-Backup.html).